# Iterate through a JSON array - Sinatra

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra, webhooks

I have a basic Sinatra app that receives a webhook from PagerDuty, grabs some of the fields and inserts a new document into MongoDB.

```
post '/webhooks/pagerduty/' do

  request.body.rewind
  json = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

  @pd_id = json["messages"][0]["data"]["incident"]["id"]
  @ts = json["messages"][0]["data"]["incident"]["created_on"]
  @status = json["messages"][0]["data"]["incident"]["status"]
  @host = json["messages"][0]["data"]["incident"]["trigger_summary_data"]["HOSTNAME"]
  @description = json["messages"][0]["data"]["incident"]["trigger_summary_data"]["SERVICEDESC"]
  @state = json["messages"][0]["data"]["incident"]["trigger_summary_data"]["SERVICESTATE"]

  # MongoDB connection code omitted

  coll = db.collection('incidents')

  _id = SecureRandom.hex

  if @status != "resolved"

    coll.insert({ :_id => _id, :pd_id => @pd_id, :ts => @ts, :status => @status, :host => @host, :description => @description, :state => @state, :db_type => @db_type })

  else

    coll.update({ :pd_id => @pd_id }, { "$set" => { :status => @status }})

  end

  status 200

end
```

This works fine but the problem is that PagerDuty sometimes sends multiple JSON objects in the array and I'm not sure how to adjust the code and iterate through the array instead of grabbing the first object in the array in a DRY manner.

Comment: Why don't you show a minimal example of the JSON so we can SEE what you're talking about, instead of making us imagine it?

Comment: It's just a JSON array: {"messages":[{"field":"value"},{"field":"value"}]}

Answer (score 1):

Since `JSON.parse(request.body.read)["messages"]` is an `Array` object, you can do a `Array#each` call on it.

```
JSON.parse(request.body.read)["messages"].each do |element|
  processed = process(element)
  processed["status"] == "resolved" ? update(processed) : insert(processed)
end

def process(element)
  # extract the required data from the json object
  # return a Hash with the data
end

def insert(hash)
  # insert
end

def update(hash)
  # update
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response. I will try this and let you know :)